# accuracy in neural learning becomes NaN (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use tensorflow to color gray-scale images. So I use `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits()` and minimize it with `tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer()`. I train it and print

```
correct_prediction = tf.norm(y_ - y_conv)
```

But after several iterations it gives me `nan`:

```
step 0, acc 2068538.88
step 1, acc 287121.97
step 2, acc 82377.69
step 3, acc 31250.95
step 4, acc 16694.72
step 5, acc 10168.58
step 6, acc 6993.02
step 7, acc nan
step 8, acc nan
step 9, acc nan
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Softmax & cross entropy loss are not the correct choices for your output layer.

First, cross-entropy minimizes entropy and requires a domain of [0, 1]. Although your pixel values might be normalized to a [0, 1] range, the way cross entropy works will not behave as you expect. Cross-entropy is optimal for classification. You should use sum of squared error for your loss.

The bigger problem is that you're applying softmax to your image. Take a look at how softmax works here, you'll get an intuitive sense for it and probably see what's going wrong:

http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html#softmax

Softmax requires that the sum of all your outputs (the pixels of your image) equal 1, meaning many pixels will be forced to 0. This is quite at odds with your loss function.

I bet what is happening is that some pixels in your labels are near 1.0 and softmax is pushing so many pixels near 0.0 that at least a few of these pixels that should be 1.0 end up with a prediction near 0.0.

Cross-entropy has an infinite loss when it's wrong by a margin of 1.0, a condition that you are forcing upon it by your choice of softmax, and hence paying for it with NaN's occurring because of extreme gradients.

The correct solution is to use unscaled output and apply square error loss to your unscaled output (no softmax, no sigmoid, no relu, just the logits, aka your output layer without anything applied on top of it).

Comment: Thanks you very march, I'm really wrong with the loss function.

Comment: Actually, I misread your question, you used sigmoid cross entropy, not softmax cross entropy. I suspect the same issue is occurring because cross entropy can still encounter the same issue, but at least sigmoid is less wrong than softmax would have been. :)

Comment: Now I'm testing my net with norm loss and it looks much better. I suppose I had an incorrect understanding of this piece of article: "he input of the model is
the grayscale image while the target output is the a*b* components
of the CIE L*a*b* colorspace.  The a*b* components are globally
normalized so they lie in the
[0; 1] range of the Sigmoid transfer function. We then scale the target output to the size of the output of
the colorization network and compute the MSE between the output
and  target  output  as  the  loss"

Comment: "compute the MSE between the output and target output as the loss," bingo, MSE = Mean Square Error. Sounds like you're on track now. :)